# Micromamba install gets stuck when run in docker container on ARM mac

Tags: docker, macos, apple-m1, mamba

When using `micromamba install` in an amd64 docker container run on M1 ARM macOS 13.5, the installation hangs indefinitely after the extraction step.

The following docker file, built with

```bash
docker build . --platform linux/amd64
```

```
FROM mambaorg/micromamba:1.4.9
COPY environment.yml /environment.yml
RUN micromamba create -vv -y -n pangolin -f /environment.yml
```

```
...
#7 20.14   Install: 117 packages
#7 20.14 
#7 20.14   Total download: 192MB
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#7 20.14 Transaction starting
```

In info log, one can see a bit more (new run hence different timings):

```
#7 21.54 info     libmamba Transfer done for 'coin-or-clp'
#7 21.54 info     libmamba Transfer finalized, status: 200 [https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/coin-or-clp-1.17.8-h1ee7a9c_0.conda] 1173622 bytes
#7 21.54 info     libmamba Download finished, validating '/opt/conda/pkgs/coin-or-clp-1.17.8-h1ee7a9c_0.conda'
```

This is what happens in debug (again different run hence ignore relative timing):

```
#7 28.93 debug    libmamba Running in-process extraction for '/opt/conda/pkgs/git-lfs-3.4.0-ha770c72_0.conda'
#7 29.03 debug    libmamba Extracted to '/opt/conda/pkgs/mpi-1.0-openmpi'
#7 29.03 debug    libmamba Decompressing '/opt/conda/pkgs/connection_pool-0.0.3-pyhd3deb0d_0.tar.bz2'
#7 29.03 debug    libmamba Running subprocess extraction '/bin/micromamba package extract /opt/conda/pkgs/connection_pool-0.0.3-pyhd3deb0d_0.tar.bz2 /opt/conda/pkgs/connection_pool-0.0.3-pyhd3deb0d_0'
```

There is absolutely no progress hereafter, even after 10 minutes. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be due to a known [QEMU issue](https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/285) combined with mamba's use of subprocesses. The interaction of QEMU and mamba was discussed extensively in this [mamba issue](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/1611). The solution that worked for me was to run the following before any `mamba install` or `mamba create`:

```
micromamba config set extract_threads 1
```

i.e. modifying the Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM mambaorg/micromamba:1.4.9
COPY environment.yml /environment.yml
RUN micromamba config set extract_threads 1 # <---- This is the added line that fixes it
RUN micromamba create -vv -y -n pangolin -f /environment.yml
```

The bug may be stochastic as it depends on multiple processes being used. If you're "lucky" you might avoid the bug most of the time.